# $E[(X-Y)^2]=0$ imply $X=Y $a.s?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

The question is actually very strict and is explained on the title:

$$E[(X-Y)^2]=0 \to X=Y  \ \ \text{a.s}$$is it true? if yes, why?

Comment: Non-degeneracy...

Comment: The only assurance Readers have that you thought about this problem before tersely posting it here is your claim that "The question is actually very strict and is explained on the title".  Many Readers (myself included) prefer to see at least a little evidence that you digested the problem statement before posting.  Terse problem statements, making them fit into a title, are possible indications that important context has been omitted, inviting Readers to use their imaginations to fill in significant gaps.  Try to think about your problem statement from that point of view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This immediately follows from the following elementary fact:

> If $\mathbb{E}[Z]=0$ and $Z$ is positive almost surely, then $Z= 0$
>   almost surely.

Answer (score 1):

If not $X=Y$ a.s., then there exists $\epsilon>0$ with $P(|X-Y|>\epsilon)>0$. Then $E[(X-Y)^2]\ge P(|X-Y|>\epsilon)\cdot \epsilon^2>0.$

Comment: this is not true, since a sequence may converge in probability but not a.s.